# Why is the kanji for haru (陽) pronounced as "yo"?

Tags: kanji, readings, multiple-readings

So I was looking up the word Haru and I saw there are many different ways it can be written in kanji (陽, 春, 晴). When I then looked up the first one to see how it is pronounced, multiple websites (one of them being google translate) give an audio that sounds nothing like the word 'haru'. It sounds more like 'yo' or some version of 'yo'.

Why is this?

Comment: You may want to look up **onyomi** and **kunyomi**. Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/68850  https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/32582  https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/52178

Answer (score 3):

As Eddie Kal has mentioned in the comments, you might want to take a look at on'yomi and kun'yomi. However, for this case in particular, はる meaning spring is always written as 春. 陽 is a nanori when pronounced はる, meaning it is usually only pronounced that way when used in names. It is typically pronounced ひ (kun'yomi) or ヨウ(on'yomi). The kanji is used in words like 太陽(たいよう) related to the sun, light, or bright personalities.

A tip on looking up words: please don't use google translate. Although it does have its own cons, a Japanese-English dictionary like Jisho.org might be better.

Comment: +1 for "don't use Google Translate".